# windows service method not working

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I am new in windows service c#. I have a class library called `JobAdminLib` which has a class call `ArchiveAutomationAdministrator`. This class has a method called `CountJobs()`. I have created a windows service which would run this particular method at the scheduled interval of time. But it does not seems to work for me. Log reports are saying its running but the function that the method is supposed to perform is not working.

I have attached code for reference

```
public class ArchiveAutomationAdministrator
{
JobRepository repository = new JobRepository();

public IEnumerable<LiveJobs> GetCurrentlyRetentionJobs(Func<LiveJobs, bool>
criteria = null)
{
return from job in repository.GetCurrentlyRetentionJobs() select job;
}

public void countJobs()
{
var count = from job in repository.GetCurrentlyRetentionJobs() select job;
int[] JobCount = new int[count.Count()];

for (int i = 1; i <= JobCount.Length; i++)
{
string jobnumber = repository.GetCurrentlyRetentionJobs().First().JobNumber;
JobAdministrator admin = new JobAdministrator(repository);
admin.ArchiveJob(jobnumber);
}
}
}
```

**Following is my windows service**

```
public partial class Scheduler : ServiceBase
{
private Timer timer1 = null;
public Scheduler()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
timer1 = new Timer();
this.timer1.Interval = 5000;
this.timer1.Elapsed += new
System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
timer1.Enabled = true;
Library.WriteErrorLog("test windows service started");
}

public void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
this.task();

Library.WriteErrorLog("Job running successfully");
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
timer1.Enabled = false;
Library.WriteErrorLog("Service Stopped");
}

public void task()
{
Library.WriteErrorLog("Inside task");

ArchiveAutomationAdministrator admin = new ArchiveAutomationAdministrator();
admin.countJobs();
}
}
```

Comment: Indenting your code would make it a heck of a whole lot more readable.

Comment: Indent your code!

Comment: Total unreadable, gives everybody here eye cancer. Please accept the edit suggestions.

Comment: Editing done... sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

check if windows servers has the authority to run 
if it Ok
go to windows service list 
1- open run cmd
2- type services.msc
3- right click on your service name 
4- in login tab click on Local System Account and Check Allow Service To Interact 
with desktop

Answer (score 0):

That countJobs method has a crazy way of enumerating a list. Its hard to tell if this will work but try the below...

```
    public void countJobs()
    {
        foreach (var job in repository.GetCurrentlyRetentionJobs())
        {
            Library.WriteErrorLog("Archiving job " + job.JobNumber);

            string jobnumber = job.JobNumber;
            JobAdministrator admin = new JobAdministrator(repository);
            admin.ArchiveJob(jobnumber);
        }
    }
```

that way you will get logging inside the loop and you'll be able to tell if there is anything to actually process.